# calling overloaded postfix unary operator twice

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unary-operator

We overload unary ++ prefix and postfix similar to the code below.
My question is about the commented line:

```
// two = (one++)++;
```

I believe I understand what is happening and that the (one++) is returning a copy of the original myInt one and the copy is then postfix incremented with (one++)++. A copy has to be returned so that the postfix of ++ is respected and the original version of myInt one assigned to myInt two.

However, given the prefix unary overload works intuitively (or at least intuitively to me):

```
two = ++(++one);
```

Is there a way to produce what I consider intuitive results for (two.value=1 and one.value=3):

```
two = (one++)++;
```

This may be more academic than practical, but I found it interesting and I couldn't come up with good search terms in researching an answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myInt
{
public:
    int value;

public:
    myInt(int n = 0)
        : value{ n }
    {
    }

    myInt& operator ++()
    {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    myInt operator ++(int)
    {
        myInt copy(value);
        ++value;
        return(copy);
    }

    void show() {
        cout << "value = " << value << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myInt one(1);
    myInt two;

    two = ++(++one); // This seems intuitive that two.value=3 and one.value=3;
    one.show(); // 3
    two.show(); // 3

    one.value = 1;

    // two = (one++)++; // Intuitively, I might expect that two.value=1 and one.value=3, but one.value = 2
    // But, this achieves more of what I expect.
    two = one++; one++;

    one.show(); // 3
    two.show(); // 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is question about? `two = (one++)++;` does not compile for native types.

Comment: I think that helps answer my question given (one++)++ for native types doesn't compile, but ++(++one) does.  My take from the compiler regarding (one++)++ on native types is that the return type of postfix ++ isn't compatible with another postfix ++. I imagine the same answer applies to why what I'm suggesting above isn't practical given what an overload of postfix ++ has to return.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make this work for a class type, *but* you probably don't want to.

When you do a post-increment, you increment the variable, but return the value it previously held. To do that, what you return is normally an rvalue, which means it's not normally open to further modification.

If you really insist on doing so just to prove the possibility, you can write a post-increment operator that returns an lvalue instead of an rvalue. But that means even though is uses post-increment syntax, you only have a couple of choices for returning an lvalue. One is to dynamically allocate an object to return. This can give proper post-increment semantics, but almost inevitably leaks the object. The other is to return the object upon which the operator was invoked. This avoids leaking an object, but means that even though you're written it to use post-increment syntax, your operator will act like a pre-increment (that is, it'll increment the value and return the incremented value, not the value it held before being incremented).

Purely for the sake of completeness, here's an implementation of the latter (but oh dear lord, please don't ever do anything like this in real code).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Horrible {
    int i = 0;
public:
    Horrible &operator++(int) { 
        ++i;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Horrible const &h) {
        return os << h.i;
    }
};

int main() {
    Horrible h;

    std::cout << (h++)++ << '\n';
}
```

Output: `2`.

But I'll repeat: this definitely falls under "stupid compiler tricks." Please don't subject the world to such nonsense in real code.